# Language in England during 1066

Tags: english, french

For how many years after 1066 did we speak French in England? I tried looking this up on many sites, but I couldn’t find anything. I'm hoping someone knows their history and can tell me when people stopped speaking French in England after 1066.

Answer (score 9):

It depends on who "we" are. French (or rather, Anglo-Norman French) was never the universal language of England, but it was the first language of the ruling class. The kings were first-language speakers of French, but Henry IV was the first king to take the oath in English. For the elite, French became a second language by the end of the 15th century. However, the written language was Latin for a couple of centuries. Bits of French persists to this day, in a fashion, [in legal language](http://lawjournal.mcgill.ca/userfiles/other/5850855-43.Baker.pdf), though in common law, French was not banished until 1731 ([4 Geo. II, c. 26](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proceedings_in_Courts_of_Justice_Act_1730)).